# How to properly implement a PHP redirect in Drupal 7.x?

Tags: php, drupal-7

**GOAL:** If the user's point of origin is London, redirect user to a specific landing page/path.

**PROBLEM:**
Implementing the following redirect methods return the following failed results:

Nothing happens >> header("http://mywebsite/subcat");

1. Too many redirects >> header("Location: http://mywebsite/subcat");
2. Too many redirects >> header("Location: /path");
3. Too many redirects >> drupal_goto("http://mywebsite/subcat");
4. Too many redirects >> drupal_goto("/path");
5. Endless loop >> JS:
   window.location.replace("http://example.com/path");

**IMPLEMENTATION:**
I hacked the below script from a few different SO posts (will give credit as soon as I remember which posts I was searching for) which when used in a stand-alone php works fine (with all the redirect methods listed above), but placed as the first block of code above the header.tpl.php (or properly inside my custom module [using hook_init]), produces the same results listed under PROBLEM.

**FUNCTION USED:**

```
        <?php

    function get_client_ip ()
    {
        if (!isset ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
            return NULL;
        }

        $proxy_header = "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR";
            if (array_key_exists ($proxy_header, $_SERVER)) {
                $client_ip = trim (end (explode (",", $_SERVER[$proxy_header])));
                if (filter_var ($client_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
                    return $client_ip;
                } else {
                    // Validation 
                }
            }
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    $ip = get_client_ip(); // the IP address to query
    $query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
    if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {

if ($query['country'] == "United Kingdom"){
        header("Location: /mypath");
        } else {
          echo 'Unable to get location';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**ASSUMPTIONS**

- Logic error in my code.
- Improper use of redirect methods/logic
- Improper placement of my code which gets overridden by the execution
  waterfall of other modules.

Comment: Unrelated to the answer you seek, but you should always call an `exit` or a `die` after issuing a location header. Code continues to execute after the header has been issued which can cause undesired side effects.

Comment: Thank you for the note @Scoots, but this did not fix it unfortunately.

Comment: Yea, I said it wasn't the answer, it's just a general rule you should follow. There was a rather fantastic tale I read about a guy who wasn't calling `exit;` after his "redirect away from admin if not logged in". Long story short, Google bot clicked on all of his "delete page" links.

Answer (score 0):

**THE AHA! MOMENT:**

I was concentrating so hard on the functionality that I totally ignored the general journey the code processing. The issue my code was failing is that I'm dealing with a CMS in regards to what 'pages' or content really is — content is dynamic and thus generated on the fly. So in my once my logic test was satisfied, the redirect lead to another piece of dynamically generated content with the same logic test. Thus I created an infinite loop.

**SOLUTION**

I modified my code to not only check for point of origin but to also check the node's id. So in other words the correct testing logic is as follows:

Test if point of origin is London and if the loaded node is not the UK landing node, then redirect to UK landing note.

You live you learn!